# Accidentally restored a another database to the 'postgres' database how to correct

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, restore

I accidentally restored another database as the default postgres database, how do I correct this?
postgres v10 on ubuntu.

Comment: Drop the database and create a new one, using template1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be specific. Log into a database other then `postgres`.

Then:

```
DROP DATABASE postgres;
CREATE DATABASE postgres; --You don't need to specify template1 it is the default.
```

Then do your restore. If you are using `pg_restore` make sure you use `-C` to have the database CREATEd properly.

Comment: I would use `template0`.